# Differences in nodejs paths between linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have create-react-app project and I have a scss file in it.
Inside this file, I have a string like `image: url("src/assets/icons/icon1.png");`
When I run `npm run start` in windows everything is ok, but whene i run the same in WSL it gives an 'icon1 file not found' error. It join current file path with target file path.
I think there is a difference between working with start of a path in windows and linux, but I can't find any info about that. 
What the differences between working with path starts in this systems and is there any way to use this code in linux without adding / in to beginning of the path?

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive. Review the case used in your path

Comment: no I'am completely sure its about / in start of a path or something like that.
I check out path cases and it's alright

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path instead for an URL e.g `image: "src/assets/icons/icon1.png";`?

Comment: No, because there is a big application, that was written on windows with using of url(...), but I want to continue development on linux without changing of every path for assets